# Orientation aware modal in portrait locked Android application using React Native

Tags: android, react-native, android-orientation

I'm working on a react-native application which is generally locked to portrait due to the nature of the app. The app is locked to portrait using the following flag in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Now I would like to have the app to be able to rotate at a certain place in the app. The Modal component in react-native seems to be the right choice for this. The Modal is configured as following:

```
<Modal
    animationType="slide"
    transparent={false}
    supportedOrientations={['portrait', 'portrait-upside-down', 'landscape', 'landscape-left', 'landscape-right']}  
>
    <View style={styles.modal}>
        <View>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
                this.setState({
                    awareVisible: false
                });
            }}>
            <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    </View>
</Modal>
```

In iOS this works fine and the view will rotate, in Android it doesn't do anything. I tried creating a custom Modal component and capture it in Android code, but this did not work for me either.

Comment: Hi, supportedOrientations in modal component only for ios.

Comment: @SathishSundharam I know that, but judging by the Modal documentation, no additional attributes are required for it to work on Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [react-native-orientation](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation) ... and because this Project seems not to be maintained anymore, it's might better to use this fork: [react-native-orientation-locker](https://github.com/wonday/)

With it, you only need to set something like this, when ever you need it:

```
Orientation.unlockAllOrientations(); //this will unlock the view to all Orientations
Orientation.lockToPortrait(); //this will lock the view to Portrait
Orientation.lockToLandscapeLeft(); //this will lock the view to Landscape
```

I've also used it at one of my App's which is forced to portrait-mode. But I need the landscape-mode to view Images of an Image-Gallery.
**Works really well on both: Android & IOS.**

Hope this helps you out.